# Bash array - do something with members that moved their position

Tags: arrays, bash

I have following simplified script with array variable:

```
array1=(`somecommand1`)

for i in ${array1[@]} ; do
echo $1
done
```

That will give me following output:

```
 1 277788
 2 283871
 3 282913
 4 283519
 5 283568
 6 283563
 7 283595
 8 278229
 9 283029
10 278654
11 280508
12 248825
13 282361
 .
```

On each script run, when the ${array1} changes, I need to run 
some command on those numbers that moved to the top of the array plus I want to check one that likely stayed unchanged issuing `checkcmd` that will get a timestamp and compares it with the timestamp from previous run.

```
 1 283563 <- moved=modified
 2 283871 <- moved=modified (overtook 277788)
 3 277788 <- modified? `checkcmd 277788` timestamp changed = modified, so check the #4
 4 282913 `checkcmd 282913` -> timestamp unchanged -> do not check further
 5 283519
 6 283568
 7 283595
 8 278229
 9 283029
10 278654
11 280508
12 248825
13 282361
```

Now I want to run `somecommand2` on those numbers identified as modified perhaps using another array:

```
array2=( 283563 283871 277788 )
for i in ${array2[@]} do
somecommand2 $i
done
```

How can I achieve that? I do not want to run `checkcmd` on each ${array1} member, because each `checkcmd` takes quite long to execute due to polling data from the server and there could be even hundreds of members in ${array1} so it would make this script unusable. 
I hope there will be some "function" that will compare arrays with each other like that and the `checkcmd`can be run only once or twice as per logic explained above.

Comment: Avoid asking multiple questions in one post.

Comment: ok I thought I should have, will remember that

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. keep a counter:

   ```
    n=0; for i in "${array1[@]}"; do printf "%2d %s\n" $((++n)) "$i"; done
   ```
2. You'll need to compare them

   ```
   for idx in "${array1[@]}"; do
       if (( ${array1[idx]} == ${array2[idx]} )); then
           echo "they are the same: ${array1[idx]}"
       else
           echo "they are the same: ${array1[idx]} <=> ${array2[idx]}"
       fi
   done
   ```

Comment: as per 2. I am not sure how to implement this idea because ${array2} is not defined anywhere? Is there a way how to store array from each run and keep it for the next run so I can compare both?

Comment: You need to use a separate variable. Once you re-assign a variable, the previous value is lost.

Answer (score 0):

Another way of printing with index, using a c-style loop

```
for (( i=0; i<${#arr1[@]}; ++i )); do
    echo $i ${arr1[i]}
done
```

Comment: thanks that resolved the first part that I edited out because it was off topic